# methods and if statements.. can someone check to see what the issue is?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, methods

```
private decimal getPrice(int intQty)
{        
    decimal decPrice; //<--- problem here @ decPrice

    if (intQty <= 500)
    {
        decPrice = 1.25m;
    }
    else if (intQty >= 501 && intQty <= 1000)
    {
        decPrice = 1.05m;
    }
    else if (intQty >= 1001 && intQty <= 5000)
    {
        decPrice = .90m;
    }
    else if (intQty > 5001)
    {
        decPrice = .75m;
    }
    return intQty;
    decimal *decPrice* = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text); 
    txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();<--problem here at txtQty
}
```

**// at the last (CONVERSION) 'decPrice', it keeps telling me it's already defined in this scope. but if i remove it, the above 'decPrice' (UNDERNEATH METHOD), says it's assigned but value never used and 'txtQty'(BELOW)  would say code unreachable.**

Comment: Your question shows a significant lack of understanding of basic coding principles.  I suggest you go backwards a few steps to easier examples until you can understand some simpler techniques.

Comment: I'm definitely still learning. It's gonna take some time, but thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
return intQty;
decimal *decPrice* = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text); 
txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();<--problem here at txtQty
```

problems:

- you have written some code after `return` statement, these are unreachable codes. when the execution reach the `return` statement it leaves the current function so any code after it is unreachable.
- `decimal *decPrice*` declares the `decPrice` variable again. it has been declared in the third line of your function already. (i don't know why it is surrounded by stars)
- you meant to return a decimal (from your function signature) and I think you should retern `decPrice` not `intQty`

Comment: and take out the return before it!

Comment: and return `decPrice` not `intQty`

Comment: @wahwahwah txtQty seems to be control

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

```
return intQty; //FIRST
decimal decPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text); //SECOND
```

As you have `return` statement anything written under it will not run. So if you remove `decimal` after return statement, the `decPrice` is not used as your method return before using it.

So right way will be to write it like this:

```
decPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text); 
txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();
return intQty;
```

PS:- Though I am not able to understand why are you using `if-else` ladder as you don't really use `decPrice` and return the value passed to function.

Comment: my professor wanted us to use if-else statements. Thanks for the help